# GAE Python NDB .put not synchronous on development (but works in production)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The following below should create a `Counter` model and use (deferred) tasks to increment the counter to 10.  Visiting `'/'` ought to create a single `Counter` object with `count = 10`.  This happens in production.  In development (localhost) multiple `Counter` objects are created with the largest being 10:

[image]

I suspect this is because the `put` is not synchronous on development (but appears to always be on production).  Is there a way to make them synchronous?

Code snippet below:

```
class Counter(ndb.Model):
  count = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)

def reset():
  ndb.delete_multi(Counter().query().fetch(keys_only=True, use_cache=False, use_memcache=False))

def increment():
  counter = Counter().query().get(use_cache=False, use_memcache=False)
  if not counter:
    counter = Counter(count=0)

  counter.count += 1
  counter.put()

  if counter.count < 10:
    deferred.defer(increment)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
  """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
  reset()
  deferred.defer(increment)
  return 'Hello World!'
```

I have a git repo that reproduces this behavior [here](https://github.com/tianhuil/appengine-python-flask-skeleton).  You can find the commit that makes the last change [here](https://github.com/tianhuil/appengine-python-flask-skeleton/commit/e32da1b4cf67c91b8838e33b26042f85e2f6856c).

Answer (score 7):

The production 'synchronicity' is just apparent, it's not guaranteed (in your approach). It can always happen that a newly created counter is not found in the query, thus your code could create multiple counters.

More details in this [Balancing Strong and Eventual Consistency with Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/) article.

Comment: To explain a bit further, in production eventual consistency means that the query *might not* (but probably will) include the newly created item. In development, that effect is intentionally exaggerated such that the query will definitely not contain the new item; this is to encourage you to deal with the possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You should retrieve your counter by key and then you will avoid eventual consistency. Especially as you seem to only create a single Counter object.  Not this won't scale if you have a large number of concurrent writes.

It would also pay to read the article linked to in the other answer.  There a re number of problems with your approach.

Its seems odd to me that you would even consider using queries for this functionality. By specifying the key you will also guarantee a single counter entity.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for answer!  Where would you suggest I store the key for the counter?

Comment: You could hard code it, or create your own settings file with it in, or define it in appengine_config.py.  Doesn't really matter other than it being maintainable and documented.