# Python Google App Engine redirect not updating content

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, post

I am using Python and Google App Engine to send a POST form to increase a likes counter. It updates the number of likes, but when redirect to home page it doesn't show the updated counter, but if I click refresh it does show the updated counter. This only happens on the first time I submit the form, the second, third and so on it shows the updated counter fine, but if I refresh again it won't show the updated counter on the first submission

```
if likePostId:
    if post.likes == None:
       post.likes = 1
    else:
       post.likes = int(post.likes) + 1
    post.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: Eventual consistency: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/

Comment: I moved the form from the homepage to the post page. In the post page it seems to update the counter without any issues. I am doing the same, submitting the form and redirecting to the same page. I wanted to be able to like a post from the homepage, but this way also works. Thanks anyways

Comment: @JuanVargas: moving from the homepage to the post page probably just changed the timing a bit and thus increased the chances of the counter value to be up2date by the time it's accessed. But it doesn't mean it'll always be up2date. See Daniel's comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29860389/4495081.